# Time complexity of graphs

Tags: graph, time-complexity

I am looking at Time complexitys of graphs. What I dont understand is, why the time complexity O|V|^2|E|)
is better than O(|E|^2|V|). In both one of them is ^2 why is one better than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, graphs often have more edges than vertices.
Consider the case where this is not true: A graph where `|E| < |V|`. Such a graph can be, for instance, a simple path where the vertices are connected to each other in a chain. And in such cases, you might ask yourself whether this structure even needs to be represented as a graph.

In more complex graphs, you will find more edges than vertices. On the other extreme, a fully connected graph has `O(|V|^2)` edges. For such graphs, you are comparing an `O(|V|^4)` algorithm with an `O(|V|^5)` algorithm.

So, although it is not true for ALL graphs, those graphs that you might encounter in practice will benefit more from an `O(|V|^2|E|)` algorithm than an `O(|E|^2|V|)` algorithm.